# YQL Losing HTML Element Attributes?

Tags: yahoo, yql, yahoo-pipes

[YQL Console Link](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url=%27http://www.cbs.com/shows/big_brother/video/%27%20and%20xpath=%27//div%5B@id=%22cbs-video-metadata-wrapper%22%5D/div%5B@class=%22cbs-video-share%22%5D/a%27)

Query:

```
select * from html where url='http://www.cbs.com/shows/big_brother/video/' and xpath='//div[@id="cbs-video-metadata-wrapper"]/div[@class="cbs-video-share"]/a'
```

Returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<query xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng"
    yahoo:count="1" yahoo:created="2011-07-09T23:14:02Z" yahoo:lang="en-US">
    <diagnostics>
        <publiclyCallable>true</publiclyCallable>
        <url execution-time="146" proxy="DEFAULT"><![CDATA[http://www.cbs.com/shows/big_brother/video/]]></url>
        <user-time>163</user-time>
        <service-time>146</service-time>
        <build-version>19262</build-version>
    </diagnostics> 
    <results>
        <a class="twitter-share-button" href="http://twitter.com/share"/>
    </results>
</query>
```

Should Return Something Similar To:

```
    <results>
        <a href="http://twitter.com/share" data-url="http://www.cbs.com/shows/big_brother/video/2045825951/big-brother-episode-1" class="twitter-share-button"></a>
    </results>
```

If I back out the query one level, it totally strips out the  element, which I could also use to get the data I need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have a new html parser that recognizes custom attributes now.

Add `compat="html5"` to trigger the new parser.

e.g.:

```
select * from html where url = "http://mydomain.com" and compat="html5"
```